# Angular POST request not returning right data

Tags: angular, post, request, frontend

I am trying to replicate a post request that I've done through Postman in Angular. In Postman works great. I'm sending data and in return I receive from DB what I need. However, I cannot seem to properly translate the request into my Angular service.

This is what I'm sending with postman:

```
{
    "component": "Hero",
    "name": "Superman"
}
```

And this is what I receive:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "heroValueses": [
            {
                "idValue": 166,
                "idRelation": null,
                "key": "true",
                "text": "S",
                "id": ""
            },
            {
                "idValue": 167,
                "idRelation": null,
                "key": "false",
                "text": "N",
                "id": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/entities/heroeList/search"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 2147483647,
        "totalElements": 2,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

In my component.ts I declare a variable that will contain an Observable of type <{id: string, text: string}>:

```
this.heroPower$ = this.service._lookupHero('Superman', 'Fly');
```

And in my service I created the following POST request:

```
public _lookupHero(component: string, name: string): Observable<{ id: string, text: string }[]> {
    const url = this.settings.url.resHeroUrl + 'heroList/search'
    const header = "Here is the header";
    const body = {
      component,
      name
    };
    console.log(body, 'bodyyyyyyyyy')
    const res = this.http.post(url, body,{headers: header}).pipe(shareReplay(),
      map(response => {
        return response;
      }),
      catchError(err => of({err}))
    );
    return new Observable<HeroesValues[]>().pipe(map(res => {
      return res.map(element => {
        return {id: element.key, text: element.text };
      })
    }));
  }
}
```

"HeroesValues" is the ts file where the model of the data to be returned should be contained. However, since I'm pretty new to this I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to understand what you're trying to do and what may be wrong there:

```js
public _lookupHero(component: string, name: string): Observable<{ id: string, text: string }[]> {
    const url = this.settings.url.resHeroUrl + 'heroList/search'

    // Headers are key value pairs, not simple strings, so this is wrong
    const header = "Here is the header";
    const body = {
      component,
      name
    };
    console.log(body, 'bodyyyyyyyyy')

    const res = this.http.post(url, body,{headers: header}).pipe(shareReplay(),
      // The map operator is used to transform a value emitted by an Observable. You're just returning the same exact value, so this is not needed
      map(response => {
        return response;
      }),

      // An Observable returned by the Angular HTTP Client will emit an error if the request fails, so manually catching and returning the error is not needed
      catchError(err => of({err}))
    );

    // You should not create a new Observable if you already have one to work with.
    return new Observable<HeroesValues[]>().pipe(map(res => {
      return res.map(element => {
        return {id: element.key, text: element.text };
      })
    }));
  }
}
```

Here's how the `lookupHero` method should be like:

```js
lookupHero(
  component: string,
  name: string
): Observable<{ id: string; text: string }[]> {
  const url = this.settings.url.resHeroUrl + 'heroList/search';
  const body = {
    component,
    name,
  };

  return this.http.post(url, body).pipe(
    map((res) =>
      res._embedded.heroValueses.map((hero) => ({
        id: hero.id,
        text: hero.text,
      }))
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Why did you go with this approach? I’ve seen other people do otherwise for similar cases. In some other cases I’ve seen the use of methods which would call the POST request and return the Observable. This is just so I can understand.

Edit: I just saw the comment lines. Thank you!